# Distorterd SCNMorpher weights animation imported from Blender

Tags: ios, scenekit, blender, collada

I'm trying to animate face morphing with Scene Kit and assets exported from Blender using SCNMorpher/Key Shapes.

In the imported DAE file I fix 2 Key Shapes with [ColladaMorphAdjuster](https://github.com/JonAllee/ColladaMorphAdjuster) and I can traverse them at

```
 node?.morpher?.targets
```

logs as

```
Optional([<SCNGeometry: 0x1c4137ca0>, <SCNGeometry: 0x1c4137d40>])
```

But the mesh gets distorted when animated like on [SCNMorpher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmorpher) docs site :

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "morpher.weights[0]")
animation.fromValue = 0.0;
animation.toValue = 1.0;
animation.autoreverses = true;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE;
animation.duration = 5;
node?.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

[image: Distortion]

I've tried setting unifiesNormals but with no result.

I cannot find the reason why those key shapes produce wrong output in Scene Kit view.

Comment: We desperately need more SceneKit Q/A, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Distortion was caused by applying modifiers on export from Blender (Apply Modifiers) - subsurf in my case.